# Having trouble sharing screen in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, skype, bug-reporting

I'm using ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I want to share my entire screen with third party applications, it just shows the cursor and blank black screen. At first I thought that the problem is with my application, but it wasn't. I tried `skype`, `discord` and online web apps but the same problem is still occurring.

[image: empty black screen with cursor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved after doing the following steps:

1. `sudo vi /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`
2. Uncomment `#WaylandEnable=false`
3. Reboot.